# How to upload images on cloudinary in ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, cloudinary

I want to upload a picture from cloudinary in a ionic2. I think that more attractive to use cloudinary. But, I don't know how I use this framework with ionic 2. Can you give me a easy example?

Answer (score 0):

**Cloudinary** provides good Angular **SDK**, you can use that.
1. Install the Javascript SDK and the Angular SDK for the relevant Angular version

The Cloudinary Angular SDKs serve as a layer on top of Cloudinary's Javascript library. Install the Cloudinary Javascript library and the relevant version of the *Angular SDK* in the format:

npm install cloudinary-core @cloudinary/angular- --save
: Enter the Angular SDK package that corresponds to the version of Angular you are using, such as 2.x, 4.x, or 5.x. For example:

npm install cloudinary-core @cloudinary/angular-5.x --save.... for more info [click here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/angular_integration#angular_version_2_and_later)

**Another very easy implementation** by Cloudinary Team: [click here](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_angular/blob/master/samples/photo_album/app/js/photo-album/photo-upload.component.ts)

**Or if** you want to use just native file transfer plugin then use:
I think this link would help you http://www.developerslearnit.com/2016/11/build-photo-gallery-app-with-ionic2.html

It is done using file transfer plugin.

```
fileTransfer.upload(this.imageNewPath, 'yourUrlHere',
      options).then((entry) => {
        this.imagePath = '';
        this.imageChosen = 0;
        loader.dismiss();
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
      }, (err) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
      });
```

Another good example is here https://devdactic.com/ionic-2-images/
This example can be used for uploading to any file hosting servers.